# Calculating arcsecant, arccosecant and arccotangent

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

I'm writing a wxWidgets C++ calculator application. I'm implementing the trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, arctan, sec, csc, cot, arcsec, arccsc, arccot). How do I calculate arcsec, arccsc and arccot of a number `n`?

Comment: Is a a pure math question (ie what is arcsec definition), or a C++ one? If you can compute `sec` you should be able to compute `asec`...

Comment: Both. Using `<cmath>` header I have functions to compute `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `asin`, `acos` and `atan`, but as for the rest of them I have to calculate them somehow. For `sec`, `csc` and `cot` I just do `1/cos`, `1/sin` and `1/tan` respectively, but for their arc's?

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions): arcsec(1/x) = arccos(x), arccsc(1/x) = arcsin(x).

Comment: I kind of suck at Maths, and I don't understand what I should write. I tried `1 / acos(n * 3.14159265 / 180)` but it doesn't work (I need the result in degrees).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For secant

```
sec(x) = 1/cos(x)
sec(x) = y <=> 1/y = cos(x) <=> x = acos( 1/y)
```

Thus

```
x = arcsec( y) = acos( 1/y)
```

The others are similar.

The arc functions have a caveat. For example if |y| > 1 then acos( y) returns nan.

You might want to include atan2 in your functions, as it is sometimes more useful than atan. For example given a vector x,y atan2(y,x) gives the direction of the vector -- the angle through which to rotate (1,0) so as to get x,y -- but atan(y/x) doesn't.

Comment: What? How do I write a function to calculate `arcsec`, `arccsc` and `arccot` in C++?

Comment: As the answer suggests, you can compute arcsec(x) as `acos(1 / x)`.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I transform it into degrees?